# Doctrine class is not a valid entity or mapped super class

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am new to Doctrine and Symfony and I am having a really difficult time creating an entity.

When running the following command:

`php app/console doctrine:generate:entities Foo/FooBundle/Entity/Company`

I am getting the following error:

```
 `[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]
  Class "Foo\FooBundle\Entity\Company" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.`
```

Entity/Company.php

```
   namespace Foo\FooBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


     /**
     *@ORM\Entity
     *@ORM\Table(name="product")
     */


class Company
{
   /*
    *@ORM\Id
    *@ORM\Column(type="integer")
    *@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    protected $id;

    /*
    *@ORM\Column(type="string", length=250)
    */
    protected $name;

    /*
    *@ORM\Column(type="string", length=650)
    */
    protected $description;
}
```

I have been trying to debug this for quite some time now, I appreciate any advice on how to troubleshoot this problem.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You're missing the `@ORM\Entity` annotation

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please see edited. That was a typo, I actually have it in my code...

Comment: What is AnnotationReader use statment for?

Answer (score 1):

Two mistakes I can see:

1. No getters and setters
2. Your annotations are in invalid format. You are missing one * at opening everywhere.

   It should be

   ```
   /**
    * @ORM\WhateverHere
    */
   ```

   And you have

   ```
   /*
    * @ORM\....
    */
   ```

Comment: 1. An entity doesn't need getters and setters to be valid.
2. Yes, this is actually correct. You probably need to add another asterisk in the first comment line, in all comments.

Comment: You're absolutely right, it can still get mapped. But he will need them if he wants to manipulate `protected` properties (in any sane way) :)